# Deriving charges from a string in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I have a column called narration in my table and its data as below.

```
NARRATION

MMT/PS/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90
MMT/43425/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90/1257874554
MMT/XX/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90
ITI/4425/chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70/1257874554
```

From narration field I want to derive charges and GST values and required output is as shown below

```
DERIVED NARRATION|Charges|GST

chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90|5.00|0.90
chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90|5.00|0.90
chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90|25.00|20.90
chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70|5.00|10.70
```

Please suggest query. I tried like as shown below

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('MMT/43425/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90/1257874554','[^/]+',1,3),'[^GSTRs]+',1,2) ,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('MMT/43425/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90/1257874554','[^/]+',1,2+1),'[^GSTRs]+',1,3)
  FROM  DUAL;
```

but it is not giving me correct output for all scenarios.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a way to get what you need:

```
select regexp_substr(narration, 'chgRs[^\/]+') as derived_narration,
       regexp_substr(narration, '(chgRs)(.+)(GSTR)', 1, 1, '', 2) as charges,
       regexp_substr(narration, '(GSTRs)(\d+\.\d+)', 1, 1, '', 2) as GST
from yourTable
```

With your sample data:

```
SQL> with yourTable(NARRATION) as (
  2      select 'MMT/PS/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90' from dual union all
  3      select 'MMT/43425/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90/1257874554' from dual union all
  4      select 'MMT/XX/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90' from dual union all
  5      select 'ITI/4425/chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70/1257874554' from dual
  6  )
  7  select regexp_substr(narration, 'chgRs[^\/]+') as derived_narration,
  8         regexp_substr(narration, '(chgRs)(.+)(GSTR)', 1, 1, '', 2) as charges,
  9         regexp_substr(narration, '(GSTRs)(\d+\.\d+)', 1, 1, '', 2) as GST
 10  from yourTable;

DERIVED_NARRATION         CHARGES    GST
------------------------- ---------- ----------
chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90        5.00       0.90
chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90        5.00       0.90
chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90      25.00      20.90
chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70      15.00      10.70
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regular expressions:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36f9bd/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( NARRATION ) AS
SELECT 'MMT/PS/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MMT/43425/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90/1257874554' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MMT/XX/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITI/4425/chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70/1257874554' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CASE FIN
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( narration, chgrs )
       ELSE SUBSTR( narration, chgrs, fin - chgrs )
       END AS derived_narration,
       SUBSTR( narration, chgrs + 5, gstrs - chgrs - 5 ) AS charges,
       CASE FIN
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( narration, gstrs + 5 )
       ELSE SUBSTR( narration, gstrs + 5, fin - gstrs - 5 )
       END AS GST
FROM   (
  SELECT narration,
         INSTR( narration, 'chgRs' ) AS chgrs,
         INSTR( narration, 'GSTRs' ) AS gstrs,
         INSTR( narration, '/', INSTR( narration, 'GSTRs' ) ) AS fin
  FROM   table_name
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36f9bd/11/0)**:

```
|    DERIVED_NARRATION | CHARGES |   GST |
|----------------------|---------|-------|
|   chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90 |    5.00 |  0.90 |
|   chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90 |    5.00 |  0.90 |
| chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90 |   25.00 | 20.90 |
| chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70 |   15.00 | 10.70 |
```

**Query 2**: However, if you do want to use regular expressions then you can use:

```
/(chgRs(\d+\.\d+)GSTRs(\d+\.\d+))(/|$)
```

Like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( narration, '/(chgRs(\d+\.\d+)GSTRs(\d+\.\d+))(/|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         AS derived_naration,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( narration, '/(chgRs(\d+\.\d+)GSTRs(\d+\.\d+))(/|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2 )
         AS charges,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( narration, '/(chgRs(\d+\.\d+)GSTRs(\d+\.\d+))(/|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 3 )
         AS gst
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36f9bd/11/1)**:

```
|     DERIVED_NARATION | CHARGES |   GST |
|----------------------|---------|-------|
|   chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90 |    5.00 |  0.90 |
|   chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90 |    5.00 |  0.90 |
| chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90 |   25.00 | 20.90 |
| chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70 |   15.00 | 10.70 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select 'MMT/PS/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90' as narration from dual union
    select 'MMT/43425/chgRs5.00GSTRs0.90/1257874554' from dual union
    select 'MMT/XX/12345/Family/RAM/chgRs25.00GSTRs20.90' from dual union
    select 'ITI/4425/chgRs15.00GSTRs10.70/1257874554' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(narration, 'chgRs\d+(\.\d{1,2})?'),
       regexp_substr(narration, 'GSTRs\d+(\.\d{1,2})?')
from data
```